# Minimum Bits needed in Floating Point Format

Tags: binary, floating-point, computer-science, precision, ieee-754

I have a task to calculate the minimum number of bits, which are required to express following numbers and meet all requirements:

min. Number: 10

max. Number: 10000000

Accuracy: 0,001% of the numbers.

I am not quite sure how to handle this task. I should be presented in a Floating Point format like IEEE...

To express the max. Number I think there are 5 Bits needed (Exponent Bits), because then I can display 2^31, which is sufficient. Since I don't need to display negative numbers, I can save the sign bit and I don't need negative numbers in the exponent, too, so I can save one Bit there as well.

In fact I am struggling with the Accuracy and I dont know how to handle that. And do I have to multiply the accuracy with my given numbers or do I have to display like 10.00001?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the ranges for binary values. To represent 100,000,000 you are going to need to be able to go up to 2^24 in your exponent (16,777,216). If 10 is the minimum value you can implicitly shift by 1 and use 2^23.

To represent values with .001 you need to be within 1/1000 or 2^10.

You need to take into account the sign bit.